# How do I fire a property changed event only after my object saved in database

Tags: hibernate, spring, events

I'm using hibernate and spring and I need to react on a property change event of a specific object.
I would like to get the event only after the data is saved in the db.
Is there a way to do so using transaction?
Does hibernate supply this option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Hibernate Interceptors or Event listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) are a common approach to meeting this requirement. If you do decide to use an interceptor, make sure to read the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html), because it can get tricky. For example, [onFlushDirty](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onFlushDirty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%5B%5D%29) is a great place to detect changes and do audit logging, however:

> Note that not all flushes end in actual synchronization with the database, in which case the new currentState will be propagated to the object, but not necessarily (immediately) to the database.

What this means is that onFlushDirty could be called any number of times with the exact same data before it's actually written to the database. To avoid duplicate logging in our example, you could try caching info about the changes you want to log, and only write them out through [postFlush](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#postFlush%28java.util.Iterator%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Hibernate Interceptor or Hibernate event listeners.  See the [Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/events.html) for more on both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use an AfterReturning aspect to do this? It can be done easily using Spring AOP

If you would have to do it using Hibernate, you would have to write a class which implements the PostUpdateEventListener Interface. 
This will ask you to provide a concrete implementation of the onPostUpdate method which will provide you a PostUpdateEvent object. 
get the entity using event.getEntity() and proceed.